# Two different derivatives at a point? What's going wrong here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers

I have a question as follows:

If $x^2+y^2=t-\frac{1}{t}$ and $x^4+y^4=t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(1,1)$ is equal to?

Now, squaring the 1st equation and substituting the value of the 2nd, I get:
$$x^2y^2=-1$$

My first question: Considering we're only dealing in real numbers and not complex, this shouldn't be possible right?

Now moving forward, if I differentiate it as it is using implicit differentiation, I get
$$2xy^2+2yx^2\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ which yields $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}= -1$$
However, if I write the final equation that I got as $$y^2=-x^{-2}$$ $$\implies 2y\frac{dy}{dx}=-1\times-2x^{-3}$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{x^3y}= 1$$

How is this possible? How can there be two different derivatives at a given point? My theory is that it is due to the fact that $x^2y^2=-1$ isnt possible in the real plane and thus we're dealing with complex numbers here. Would any of the above answers, i.e., $-1$ or $1$ be correct if we're talking about only the real plane?

And even if we're dealing with complex numbers, how can there exist two derivatives at a single point, or does the meaning of derivative as we know in the real plane isn't quite valid? [Note: My book gives $1$ as the answer key but I'm not so sure.] Any explanation/insight would help.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ functions of $t$? Or is $t$ just some constant?

Comment: If you have $x^4+y^4=t^2+t^{-2}$ and $x=y=1$, then $t=\pm 1$. But then we can't also have $x^2+y^2=t-t^{-1}$, because the right-hand side of that is $0$ when $t=\pm 1$. How are those equations supposed to fit together?

Comment: @Arthur t is just a parameter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is purely illustrative:

To illustrate why this is a complex function:

[image]
[image]

Notice the gaps between the curves - they do not intersect for real $x$ and $y$ at any value of $t$, but they get increasingly close. Also, the curves do not even *appear* for values of $t$ between zero and one. Additionally, the two derivatives at $(1,1)$ is because $(1,1)$ is not a valid point of the domain of the curve of $x,y$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $1^4+1^4=t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}$ according to the question? You have a minus on the RHS instead. And this equation is only satisfied for $t=\pm 1$; there are no complex solutions for $t$. So not even making $t$ complex can get $(1,1)$ to be on the curve.

Comment: @Troposphere good catch, I’ve removed that section of the answer

Comment: Thanks and I accepted this answer as this contained the graphs and helped me understand the situation better although the other answer was helpful too and I've upvoted it. Just felt like this helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in saying that you don't have any real functions satisfying these equations. The point $(1,1)$ is not on the curve so the question is wrong.

[If $1+1=t-\frac 1 t$ and  $1+1=t^{2}+\frac  1 {t^{2}}$  then we get $4=t^{2}+\frac  1 {t^{2}}-2$ from the first equation so $4=2-2=0$ a contradiction].

Comment: They used the point $(1,1)$ as asked in the question

Comment: @FShrike The question is wrong since you cannot have $x=y=1$.